# How to verify whether localhost username and password is correct or not using java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, odbc, localhost

I've been looking for verification of localhost(in my case XAMPP) username and password i.e 'root' and '' (null). Suppose user changed localhost username and password then how can we verify that using java + SQL QUERY.

```
    //Database credentials
    public static  Connection conn = null;
    public static  Statement stmt = null;   
    public static  String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    public static  String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
    System.out.println("Driver LOADED");    
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_URL , LH_USERNAME , LH_PASSWORD);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Is there any way i can get Boolean result while executing one of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_URL , LH_USERNAME , LH_PASSWORD);`

whit try catch block in this way:

`try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_URL , LH_USERNAME , LH_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            if(e.getMessage().startsWith("Access denied for user")){
                System.out.println("Error: nont valid user or password");
                //you can add return false if you want
                return false;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_URL , LH_USERNAME , LH_PASSWORD);
```

When this line executes if DB_URL , LH_USERNAME , LH_PASSWORD are not correct according to you database then you will get run time exception may SQLException . if some change then verify again then add following code

```
  Connection conn = null; 
  try{
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");          
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL , LH_USERNAME,LH_PASSWORD); 
  }catch(Exception e) {    
  e.printStackTrace();  
  }
```

if you get exception (conn==null) this means you are not able to connect with database. if you do not have correct DB_URL , LH_USERNAME , LH_PASSWORD then you will get run time exception when you try to execute following line

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL , LH_USERNAME,LH_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help, Also i would like add one more point we have to be careful while changing the localhost username and password, like
Set up following settings while creating user on local Host ::
User name   :: your_username
Host name   :: localhost
Password    :: your_password
Global Privileges  :: ALL PRIVILEGES 
Grant           :: Yes